# Overly complicated parser combinator

Tags: parsing, haskell

I recently started to learn Haskell in order to write some small tools for me. Currently I'm working on a program which calculates how much steam a (railcraft) boiler of a given size outputs per tick.

In the console the user inputs a string of the following format: `S | L | BL-Size | BH-Size`, example *BH-3x3x4*

I then use ParserCombinators from the [Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) library to parse this string into a custom type. However I think my parser is overly complicated. Any suggestions how to simplify the following code?

```
module Boilers (Boiler(..), Tank(..)) where

data Boiler = Hobbyist | Locomotive | Boiler (Int, Int, Int) Tank deriving (Show)
data Tank = HighPressure | LowPressure deriving (Eq, Show)

module BoilerParser where

import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Control.Applicative
import Boilers
import Data.Maybe

boiler :: ReadP Boiler
boiler = do
  b <- standard <++ hobbyist <++ locomotive
  maybe pfail return b

standard :: ReadP (Maybe Boiler)
standard = do
  satisfy (\c -> toUpper c == 'B')
  t <- fmap (\t -> case toUpper t of
    'H' -> Just HighPressure
    'L' -> Just LowPressure
    _   -> Nothing) get
  satisfy (== '-')
  s <- BoilerParser.size
  case t of
    Nothing -> pfail
    (Just a) -> return (Just (Boiler s a))

hobbyist :: ReadP (Maybe Boiler)
hobbyist = fmap (\c -> if toUpper c == 'H' then Just Hobbyist else Nothing) get

locomotive :: ReadP (Maybe Boiler)
locomotive = fmap (\c -> if toUpper c == 'L' then Just Locomotive else Nothing) get

size :: ReadP (Int, Int, Int)
size = do
  x <- size' 1
  satisfy (== 'x')
  y <- size' 1
  satisfy (== 'x')
  z <- size' 1
  return (x,y,z)

size':: Int -> ReadP Int
size' ds = fmap read (count ds (satisfy isDigit))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boiler :: ReadP Boiler
boiler
  =   Hobbyist <$ char 'H'
  <|> Locomotive <$ char 'L'
  <|> flip Boiler <$ char 'B'
    <*> (HighPressure <$ char 'H' <|> LowPressure <$ char 'L')
    <*> ((,,) <$ char '-'
      <*> (read <$> munch1 isDigit) <* char 'x'
      <*> (read <$> munch1 isDigit) <* char 'x'
      <*> (read <$> munch1 isDigit))
```

By changing the internal definition of Boiler you can clean up that flip.

By also changing the user interface you can use the Read instance deriver:

```
data Boiler = H | L | BL Int Int Int | BH Int Int Int deriving (Read, Show)
```

Your example would then look like `BH 3 3 4`.

By the way, whereever you're using the Eq instance of Tank, consider pattern matching instead.

Comment: Tanks for the answer. I'll look into changing the definitions.But I'm a bit puzzled about the `<$` operator ? What does it do? Is it simply a left biased `$` or does it do something else?

Comment: It is the thing with the characteristic property of having the type signature `Functor f => a -> f b -> f a` :P.  `a <$ b = fmap (const a) b`. Note the existence of hayoo.fh-wedel.de .

Comment: Yeah, I searched Hoogle, but found nothing the first time. Second time it was there. Anyway: Additional question: You said I can change my data so I can use the `Read` instance deriver. Care to elaborate? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Using `data Boiler = H | L | BL Int Int Int | BH Int Int Int deriving (Read, Show)` instead of your definitions of Boiler and Tank will give you access to, for example, `readLn :: IO Boiler`, which turns an input line like "BH 3 3 4" into a Boiler value.